# laravel 8 is not loading css and js/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I don't know why, this isn't my first project in laravel but my css isn't working and I can't find any problem in my code, maybe i'm tired or something but this kept me stuck for about 10hours.

It seems that my CSS isn't working, why? I dont know, I have all my folders in the public folder and my website it's not looking at all like the template.

```html
<link href="{{ asset ('animate.css/animate.css') }}'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset ('fontawesome/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,800,900') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset ('chosen/chosen.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset ('jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset ('pentix/css/pentix.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset ('css/pex-theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I don't see any error in the terminal neither when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, all the CSS links are oppening.

Comment: `ctrl-u` only shows the source code, right? Try `F12` (your browser's DevTools)

Comment: Just in case, I would remove the space between `asset` and the file location.

Comment: it seems that i get this error when i press f12 GET http://localhost/APCService/public/animate.css/animate.css' net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) but the file is in the specific folder "animate.css" @brombeer

Comment: @Bennett i did that, no changes

Comment: Looks like your server is not setup the right way. Which server are you using? Try running your site using `php artisan serve` and see if that works. `/public/` should not appear in an URL, it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your server

Comment: I use xampp to open the project, not the `php artisan serve` command. If i delete /public/ from the url it opens only the html and i get the same error for every css and js files. i will try to open via `php artisan serve' @brombeer

Comment: No need to _remove_ `public` from the url. "Best" would be to set up a VirtualHost in XAMPP and make its DocumentRoot the `public` folder of your project (that's kind of what `php artisan serve` does, serve your files from the `public` folder)

Comment: @brombeer i tried to use `php artisan serve` it opens the server but when i try to open it on chrome it automaticly close the server

Comment: Don't use `asset()` for urls. `asset` is for files you have locally (in your public folder). Remove `asset()` for the fonts.googleapis links

Comment: Just include /public in url's and use php artisan serve. No matter if you are using Xampp

Comment: Can you share with us how do you structure your assets files ?

Comment: When you use php artisan serve, and if the server shuts down, then you got an error. Can you share that error from the terminal

Comment: @Salemloress here is my path. i don`t know what u mean by structure C:\xampp\htdocs\APCService\public

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene this is the error:  Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sat May 29 10:40:52 2021] PHP Fatal error:  Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\APCService\server.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene i thins that my server.php file is missing from my project?? where do i have to create one?

Comment: @PaulCatalinAgighioleanu first no need to include asset function when you can provide full path like https://fonts.... second I think you duplicate animate.css are you sure 'animate.css' exist on folder called "animate.css" ?

Comment: @Salemloress yes. the folder is named animate.css and the file is named animate

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

```
<link href="{{ asset ('animate.css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset ('fontawesome/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,800,900" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ asset ('chosen/chosen.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset ('jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset ('pentix/css/pentix.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset ('css/pex-theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You have extra ' in your first asset css here

```
mate.css') }}'"
```

If any js or css doesn't working simply try by checking on url like

http://localhost:8000/animate.css/animate.css

and use `php artisan serv` to run laravel application

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax to link scrripts and css in laravel is:

link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('new_assets/assets/css/style.css')}}"

i have used this in my laravel project my css file are in the "new_assets/assets/css/style.css".
**the first "asset" word within two opening courly braces it points to the laravel/public folder.make sure when you are using {{asset('some path')}} then that css or file/folder is in the public folder.**

Comment: all my css folders are in public that`s why i use this  {{asset('some path')}}.  i changed the syntax like you said but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
<link href="{{asset('animate.css/animate.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('fontawesome/css/all.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,800,900')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('chosen/chosen.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('pentix/css/pentix.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{asset('css/pex-theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="{{ public_path ('animate.css/animate.css') }}'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ public_path ('fontawesome/css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ public_path ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ public_path ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,800,900') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ public_path ('chosen/chosen.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ public_path ('jquery-ui-custom/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ public_path ('pentix/css/pentix.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ public_path ('css/pex-theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```